# ArcGis Pro: join attributes through restful api / web service

Tags: rest, arcgis

Is it possible to join attributes coming from a restful api or web service to a record in a feature class by using an attribute from the feature class?
So that ArcGis queries a web-service for each row in the feature class using an attribute value for each row in the query string. And could this map be published in ArcGis-online?

Comment: You mention ArcGIS Pro in your title but you question body suggests that you are using other parts of the ArcGIS platform instead. What precisely have you tried?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm pretty new to the ArcGis world ;)
I'm using ArcGis pro but I guess the same can be achieved by ArcGis desktop? I'm just wondering if this kind of thing is possible and if there are any resources that could help me in the right direction.

Comment: For questions on the ArcGIS platform I think you would be best researching/asking at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea is conceptually wrong: instead of joining, you can push / synchronize the attributes by updating the feature layer:

https://developers.arcgis.com/net/10-2/desktop/guide/edit-features.htm